# When I create a daemon with perl and write something to a file, it fails

Tags: perl

I use daemonize to create a daemon process and then write something to the file named log,
but when I ran it, it did not work.

Why could I not write to the log?

```
use POSIX;

sub daemonize{
    chdir '/';
    umask 0;
    open STDIN,'/dev/null'   || die "can not open /dev/null:$!";
    open STDOUT,'>/dev/null' || die "can not open /dev/null:$!";
    open STDERR,'>/dev/null' ||die "can not open /dev/null:$!";
    defined ($pid=fork) || die "can not fork a process:$!";
    exit if $pid;
    setsid || die "can not create session:$!";
}

&daemonize;
open LOG,">>/dev02/ycq/test/log" ||die "can not open file:$!";
my $num=0;
while(1){
    print LOG "$num\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: FYI, "it did not work" is a very poor problem description. If you get no errors, no output, etc, say that explicitly. That way we don't have to ask you to specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `open` (or any other function or subroutine), you need to take into consideration the [operator precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity). In your case, the `||` operator has higher precedence than the `,` (comma) operator.

Your lines that look like this:

```
open LOG, "file.txt" ||die "can not open file:$!";
```

Actually mean this, when precedence is taken into consideration:

```
open LOG, ("file.txt || die ...);
```

Since `"file.txt"` is a true statement, it will never trigger the `die` statement.

What you need is either:

```
open(LOG, "file.txt") || die ...
```

or

```
open LOG, "file.txt" or die ...
```

In the first case, the parens override the operator precedence, in the second case, the `or` operator has lower precedence than the comma operator.

What all this means is that your `open` calls may have failed silently.

Comment: thank you for your help...as you said i do not consider the precedence .maybe the reasion is about buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what error(s) do you get?  You may be [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) .

You should use the 3-argument forms of open.

Your `chdir` isn't going to put you where you think; you have written ' /' with leading whitespace.

You might find [Proc::Daemon](https://metacpan.org/module/Proc%3a%3aDaemon) useful, too.

Comment: thank you very much ! After read your linked files，I felt very benefit!

Answer (score 0):

And maybe because there's an extra space in `chdir(' /')`.